# How to pass an html object through ActionLink from a Display Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Inside my display template for `Day`, when I do the following it works:

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Days")`

However, I would like to pass the id of the day to the controller action. So when I try to do this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Days", new {id = m.Id})`

it throws an error saying:

`Cannot resolve action Edit` and suggests that I create a new controller called `Shared` with an action `Edit`. My display template is in a folder called `Shared` which could explain this suggested action.

How do I pass the id to a controller of my choice from the display template?

Edit: Entire display template code looks like this-

```
@model HashSet<Models.Day>

@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    @Html.Label(m.dayOfWeek) <br />
    @Html.Label("Start Time " + m.startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString())
    @Html.Label("End Time " + m.endTime.TimeOfDay.ToString())
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Days", htmlAttributes: new object{id = m.Id})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this overload.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Days", new {id = m.Id}, null)
```

This passes the id as a parameter to the `Edit` action of the `Days` controller.